# Simple animations in Ionic Framework

Tags: jquery, cordova, animation, ionic-framework

Can I create simple animations in views of ionic framework. The animations would be very simple ones, like changing of colour, fading, increasing height and width of elements, much like animations jquery does in web pages.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, have a look on this.

A powerful javascript animation engine for web and hybrid mobile apps, inspired by Facebook Pop, built by the **Ionic team**.

https://github.com/driftyco/collide

```
var animation = collide.animation({
  // 'linear|ease|ease-in|ease-out|ease-in-out|cubic-bezer(x1,y1,x2,y2)',
  // or function(t, duration),
  // or a dynamics configuration (see below)
  easing: 'ease-in-out', 
  duration: 1000,
  percent: 0,
  reverse: false
});

// Actions, all of these return `this` and are chainable
// .on('step' callback is given a 'percent', 0-1, as argument (for springs it could be outside 0-1 range)
// .on('stop' callback is given a boolean, wasCompleted
animation.on(/step|destroy|start|stop|complete/, function() {})
animation.once(...) //same event types
animation.off(...) //works like jquery.off
animation.stop(); //stop/pause at current position
animation.start(shouldSetImmediately); //start from current position
animation.restart();
animation.velocity(n) //starts the animation going at the given velocity ,relative to the distance, decaying
animation.distance(n); //distance for the velocity to be relative to
animation.destroy(); //unbind all events & deallocate

animation.isRunning(); //boolean getter

//These are getters and setters.
//No arguments is a getter, argument is a chainable setter.
animation.percent(newPercent, shouldSetImmediately); //0-1
animation.duration(duration); //milliseconds
animation.reverse(isReverse);

animation.easing(easing); //setter, string|function(t,duration)|dynamicsConfiguration.
// Dynamics configuration looks like this one of these:
// animation.easing({
//   type: 'spring',
//   frequency: 15,
//   friction: 200,
//   initialForce: false
// });
// animation.easing({
//   type: 'gravity',
//   bounce: 40,
//   gravity: 1000,
// });
```

Comment: Do you know where I might find an example of this API being used in an Ionic App? Is this code that you would add to a directive?

Comment: An example is given in the repo , see *test.html* : https://github.com/driftyco/collide/blob/master/test.html

Answer (score 1):

Animations in ionic are just the same as if you were working on a standard html page, the only difference is how to set it up in angular.

It is within the controller that is assigned to a view that you can add your code.

```
.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // Jquery animation
    $(selector).animate({params},speed,callback);

    // Greensock animation
    var photo = document.getElementById("photo"); //or use jQuery's $("#photo")
    TweenLite.to(photo, 1.5, {width:100});

    // or define a function and call it when you want an animation to run
    $scope.animate = function(element) {
        $(element).animate({params},speed,callback);
    }
}])
```

Thats the gist of it, you can look into more detailed stuff on [YearOfMoo](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/12/staggering-animations-in-angularjs.html)

Comment: So are you providing the recommendation to add Greensock or jQuery along with the Ionic Framework? Is that duplicating any code already embedded in the Ionic Framework designed to handle animations? Also isn't it a better practice to add the animation actions and triggers into a directive and not the controller?

Comment: I'm not recommending anything other than what I did to solve my problem at the time, and it worked brilliantly for me :) Ionic doesn't have the animation capabilities greensock offers but Year of Moo shows how to integrate it into angular so it was a good fit for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Nothing in Ionic would prevent this. Did you actually try it? Or are you asking if Ionic *ships* with anything like that? As far as I know the answer would be no.

Comment: I dont know how would I go on about trying this. Normally, I would do these kinds of stuffs in jquery but where do I write jquery in ionic!